# Creating an Ember CLI in-app/in-repo Addon: how to install npm dependencies?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I have an "in-app" (or "in-repo") Ember addon in my project's `lib` directory. The addon has its own dependencies listed in its own `package.json` file. My project's top level `package.json` specifies the addon path:

```
  "ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "lib/my-addon-here"
    ]
  }
```

However, when I run `npm install` at the project root, it does not install the addon's dependencies.

Is there a way to configure this so that the addon's dependencies are installed when running `npm install` from the project root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

List dependencies in the host app's `package.json`.

The in-repo addon's `package.json` is used only for reading some configuration from it. For example, this is how `ember-cli-deploy` determines which addons are deploy plugins.

If you do want to separate dependencies, then create a regular addon. Use `npm link` in the addon and then `npm link <addon-name>` in the host app to simplify addon development.

From @jelhan: For linting to work properly, Node dependencies that you `require()` in the addon should be listed in the addon's `package.json` as well. [See for more details](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8740).